# Custom Function in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to create custom smarty function. I have created function
<?php
/*
* Smarty plugin
* -------------------------------------------------------------
* File:     function.test.php
* Type:     function
* Name:     vbchecker
* Purpose:  check string length and outputs a response
* -------------------------------------------------------------
*/

```
 function smarty_function_vbchecker($params, &$smarty)
{
    $length = strlen($params['vbstring']);
    $output = "Your sentence is too long. Shorten It!";
    if($length < 50)
        $output = "Your sentence is just right!";
   
    return $output;
}
?>
```

I have saved the file in smarty/libs/plugins directory. After that i have created template file testfunction.tpl

```
{vbchecker vbstring='See, it is very easy to write a function.'}
```

I have saved the file in smarty/templates directory

I have also created file testfun.php which i am calling to see the output.

```
<?php
require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
     
$smarty = new Smarty;
     

    $smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
    ?>
```

but when i run the testfun.php i see error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'tesfunction.tpl'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('tesfunction.tpl', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\testfun.php(7): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('tesfunction.tpl') #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

what is the cause of this. what should i do to see the output.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template ".\templates\testfunction.tpl" on line 9 "{vbchecker vbstring='See, it is very easy to write a function.'}" unknown tag "vbchecker"' in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:656 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(441): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unknown tag "vb...', 9) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2393): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag('vbchecker', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3096): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_r36() #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3196): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_reduce(36) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler. in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 656
```

Comment: Is your template file actually called `tesfunction.tpl` or `tes` **`t`** `function.tpl`?

Comment: it iwas testfunction.tpl. after making it testfunction.tpl now i am getting error:

Comment: Question still says `testfun.php` and `$smarty->display('tesfunction.tpl');`. Can you update it to exactly what your source code is now?

Comment: testfun.phpis the file that i am calling to see the result. testfunction.tpl is the template file where i have called the function {vbchecker vbstring='See, it is very easy to write a function.'}

Answer (score 1):

You can also access static method in php for example:

```
class Foo {
   public static function boo($var) {
   // Your code
      return $var;
   }
}
```

in smarty just call:

```
{Foo::boo('my text')}
```

If You use namespaces add it. I don't use smarty functions anymore.